# Resolvent operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Let's consider the following operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$
$$A(t)=\Delta+b(t,x)\cdot\nabla$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $b(\cdot,\cdot)$ a smooth vector field.
How to compute the resolvent operator?